# Write the function most_factors(numbers) that returns the integer from the list numbers that has the most factors (divisors without remainder)

Tags: python, integer

I have to write a function `most_factors(numbers)` that would return the integer from the list numbers that have the most factors.

`>>> most_factors([5,10,16,20,25])`
would return `# 6 factors, i.e., [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20]`

I know how to find factors of numbers
`def get_factors(n):`

```
lc =[ x for x in range(1, n + 1) if n % x == 0]
return lc
```

I feel like I have to use `max()` but I have to use list comrpehension

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You apply the get_factors function to each of the numbers, and then report the one that has the most factors.  There are *many* references on line to help you find the largest number of a sequence under various circumstances.  Note that "I have no clue" usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: I spent the whole day honestly and my tutor refuses to help with this, but thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the "get_factors" function already defined:

```
def most_factors(x):
    factors = []
    lengths = []
    for i in x:
        factors.append(get_factors(i))
        lengths.append(len(get_factors(i)))
    return factors[lengths.index(max(lengths))]
```

Using list comprehension:

```
def most_factors(x):
    factors = []
    lengths = []
    [factors.append(get_factors(i)) for i in x]
    [lengths.append(len(get_factors(i))) for i in x]
    return factors[lengths.index(max(lengths))]
```

Comment: how do I write it using list comprehension?

Comment: No problem, hope it's useful